# How to automatically increment gem version and push gem to server?

Tags: ruby, deployment, rubygems, continuous-integration

Is there a way to automate the process of bumping the version number of a gem (say like in a Rake task) and pushing it to a local gem server so that it is available to everyone else?

I have had a look at [gem-release](https://github.com/svenfuchs/gem-release) and [gem_version](https://github.com/jeffp/gem_version), but they rely on using git as your VCS. I don't use git so these gems do not work for me.

What is the generally accepted state-of-the-art with regards to this process?

Comment: `gem-release` should do it, it seems like only parts of it are tied to git. If not, you could just pull that part of the code out

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thanks. Although I'm really surprised that there's no tool that does what I want out of the box.